# Chromedriver localhost with random port "The operation has timed out"

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

Have a question about selenium chromedriver. I have some tests running on AzureDevops CI. And some random amount of tests fails with exception:

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50080/session timed out after 60 seconds.
----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out.
```

Port number is random every time.

Here is the code of launching chrome:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Nothing special, but for some reason tests continue to fail. Runs on my local pc is stable, something wrong happens during CI runs

Here is full stacktrace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at ClickBrainAutomation.Common.ConditionsHook.SetUp() in C:\agent_pool\agent_0\_work\610\s\ClickBrainAutomation\Common\ConditionsHook.cs:line 82
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.SynchronousBindingDelegateInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<InvokeBindingDelegateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.SynchronousBindingDelegateInvoker.InvokeBindingDelegateAsync(Delegate bindingDelegate, Object[] invokeArgs)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.SynchronousBindingDelegateInvoker.InvokeDelegateSynchronously(Delegate bindingDelegate, Object[] invokeArgs)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioStart()
   at ClickBrainAutomation.Features.AdFeature.ScenarioStart()
   at ClickBrainAutomation.Features.AdFeature.AdStatusesLifecycle() in C:\agent_pool\agent_0\_work\610\s\ClickBrainAutomation\Features\AdsFeature.feature:line 145
--WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
--TearDown
   at ClickBrainAutomation.Common.ConditionsHook.AfterScenario() in C:\agent_pool\agent_0\_work\610\s\ClickBrainAutomation\Common\ConditionsHook.cs:line 95
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioEnd()
   at ClickBrainAutomation.Features.AdFeature.TestTearDown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use visual studio 2017 to run the test on your local pc. You should run your azure devops pipeline on hosted agent **vs2017-win2016**. If you use visual studio 2019 on your local machine. Then hosted agent **windows-2019** should be used.

If the Selenium.WebDriver.Chrome package you used was 2.43 version. You can try downgrading to version 2.40.0.

You can also have a try to pass the directory path of ChromeDriver.exe binary, when `new ChromeDriver("full path to the directory containing ChromeDriver.exe", option)`. See below:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ChromeWebDriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver(path, option, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(130));
```

For more information please check out [this thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5457).

If above workarounds donot work. You can [create a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local pc to run your UI test. (noted: self-hosted Windows agents must be configured to run as an interactive process with auto-logon enabled. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-self-hosted-windows-agents))

Comment: I guess (no-sandbox) option was the solution, idk why, but thank you!